# 3d drone and Euler angles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use tikz to draw the picture that I uploaded. I can't indicate angles and create something similar to the picture. [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[black!50] (2.5,1) ellipse (1 and 0.5);

%\fill[black!50][rotate=-30] (-2.5,1) ellipse (1.5 and 0.5);

\fill[black!50] (-2.5,1) ellipse (1 and 0.5);

\fill[black!50] (2.5,-1) ellipse (1 and 0.5);

\fill[black!50] (-2.5,-1) ellipse (1 and 0.5);

\fill[black!50] (-0,-0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.5);

\draw[black, ultra thick] (1.,.4) -- (2.5,1);

\draw[black, ultra thick] (-1.,.4) -- (-2.5,1);

\draw[black, ultra thick] (1.,-.4) -- (2.5,-1);

\draw[black, ultra thick] (-1.,-.4) -- (-2.5,-1);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well you should use the `rotate` option for the ellipsis, I suppose. Further you could use `\includegraphics{}` in a tikZ node together with `opacity=0.5` to put the picture you want to copy in the background such that it is easier to duplicate it. An example for angles is at https://texample.net/tikz/examples/angles-quotes/

Answer (score 2):

TikZ might not be the best tool for diagrams in 3d but it has of support in the form of the `3d` and the `perspective` library.

Furthermore, there are [`tikz-3dplot`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot) and [`tikz-3dtools`](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools).

I'm not sure how your blue coordinate system works and how it lies in the world.
The blue *y* axis is defined in relation to main red dashed one which makes it easy to draw an arc between them. The `angles` library only works in the *canvas* coordinate system (the one with units) which is always 2d.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, arrows.meta, calc, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x = ( 20:-2cm), y = (-30: 2cm), z = ( 80: 1.6cm),
  > = Triangle]
\draw coordinate (O) (0,0,-.05) ellipse [radius=.2];

\foreach \xy/\yx in {x/y, y/x} {
  \fill[white] (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx = -.05) -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx=-.05)
            -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx =  .05) -- (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx= .05) -- cycle;
  \foreach \lmr in {-.05, 0, .05}
    \draw[gray] (xyz cs: \xy=-1, \yx = \lmr) -- (xyz cs: \xy=1, \yx=\lmr);
  \draw[fill=white, radius=.15] (xyz cs: \xy = -1) ellipse[]
                                (xyz cs: \xy =  1) ellipse[];
}
\draw[fill=white] (O) ellipse [radius=.2];

\foreach \xyz/\Label/\Ang in {% \Ang needs to start with a ,
  x/left/ {, longitude = 70},
  y/right/{, longitude =-20},
  z/above/{, longitude = 70, latitude=70}%
} {
  \draw[->, densely dashed, red] (0, 0, 0) -- ++(xyz cs: \xyz= 1.5)
    coordinate (ax-\xyz) node[\Label] {$\xyz$};
  \draw[blue, ->]
     (0, 0, 0) -- (xyz spherical cs: radius = 1.5,/tikz/style/.expanded=\Ang)
      coordinate (ax-\xyz') node[\Label] {$\xyz$};
}

\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  (0, 1) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=20, radius=1]
  node[midway, below right] {$\varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me to add other angles: \theta and \sai, as well as XYZ, coordinate?